# is it possible to add code to a list in python

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

rows_needed = 2
result = [['text1', 'text2'], ['text3']]
menu_layout = []

for x in range(0,rows_needed):
    temp = []
    try:
        temp.append(sg.Button(c) for c in result[x])
    finally:
        pass
    menu_layout.append(temp)
    print(menu_layout)
layout = [[sg.Button(c) for c in result]]
window = sg.Window('', menu_layout)

window.read()
```

so im attempting to create a nested list for menu layout,
the result i want would be for example

```
menu_layout = [[sg.Button('text1'), sg.Button('text2')], [sg.Button('text3')],]
```

im using pysimplegui

my current code at the top gives the following result in powershell

> ```
> [[<generator object menu.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000016308733AE0>]]
> [[<generator object menu.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000016308733AE0>],
> [<generator object menu.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000016308733C30>]]
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\cafemax\projects\POS\POS\Client_Posv2.py", line 713, in
> <module>
>     menu()   File "C:\Users\cafemax\projects\POS\POS\Client_Posv2.py", line 532, in menu
>     window = sg.Window('', menu_layout)   File "C:\Users\cafemax\.venvs\stockcontrol\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py",
> line 9604, in __init__
>     self.Layout(layout)   File "C:\Users\cafemax\.venvs\stockcontrol\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py",
> line 9783, in layout
>     self.add_rows(new_rows)   File "C:\Users\cafemax\.venvs\stockcontrol\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py",
> line 9753, in add_rows
>     self.add_row(*row)   File "C:\Users\cafemax\.venvs\stockcontrol\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py",
> line 9708, in add_row
>     if element.ParentContainer is not None: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'ParentContainer'
> ```

the reason im trying to do this is because i need to be able to generate a variable amount of buttons based on the size of a list so i can't hard code this.

any help on how to fix  this or change must make to my append

Comment: Please develop this in isolation. In other words, extract a [mcve]. As a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour]. Concerning the error, it complains about a field that isn't even in the code you provide.

Comment: You'll want something like `temp = [sg.Button(c) for c in result[x]]` without the try/append stuff.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt ive edited the code so it should correspond

Comment: Okay, first question now: What's the point of the `try`/`finally`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i was setting it up for handling errors, and thought i would need it while iterating through a nested list. as i needed it the previous time i tried doing something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` doesn't contain `sg.Button` objects, it contains generators because that's what you appended to it. You don't want to create `temp` and then `append` the generator to it, you want to *`extend`* your list with your generator. See [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/843953)

```
for x in range(0, rows_needed):
    temp = []
    try:
        temp.extend(sg.Button(c) for c in result[x])
    finally:
        pass
    menu_layout.append(temp)
```

Alternatively, you can simply create `temp` using a list comprehension:

```
for x in range(0, rows_needed):
    temp = []
    try:
        temp = [sg.Button(c) for c in result[x]]
    finally:
        pass
    menu_layout.append(temp)
```

I'm not sure what the `try..finally` is for, it doesn't seem to be doing anything, but I left it in because that's not the question you're asking.

Comment: this is the solution i came up with after AKX mentioned it, i have also removed the try/finally from it, thankyou for the answer